# Trying to make a Mongo FluentAggregation with map/zip more typesafe

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a working Mongo query which uses a .Map.Lookup.Project sequence to return a new structure, however I've not been able to figure out a way to get it to work without having a big chunk of BSON in the middle of it which means that segment is no longer type-safe and affects the ability to refactor without manual oversight. I was wondering whether there was a better way of dealing with this?

Input Collections:

```
{
"_id" : UUID("6651b1b4-4607-4f7a-8904-521c364a603e"),
"SeriesIds" : [ 
    {
        "SeriesId" : "sid-1003051"
    }, 
    {
        "SeriesId" : "sid-4010016"
    }, 
    {
        "SeriesId" : "sid-4021016"
    }, 
    {
        "SeriesId" : "sid-4021017"
    }, 
    {
        "SeriesId" : "sid-4021018"
    }, 
    {
        "SeriesId" : "sid-4021070"
    }
]}

{
"_id" : "id-1",
"petchem_price_specifications" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "sid-4048001",
        "type" : "prices.price_assessments_specifications"
    },
    {
         "id" : "sid-1003051",
        "type" : "prices.price_assessments_specifications"
    }
],
"price_offerings" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "E-ETHBZ",
        "tier" : "LEGACY-PRICE"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "E-ETHBZ-STD",
        "tier" : "STD"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "E-ETHBZ-STDPLUS",
        "tier" : "STDPLUS"
    }
]}
```

Output structure:

```
UserId : Guid
SeriesIds : [{
     SeriesId : string
     Entitlements : [{
         Name : string
         Tier : string
     },{...}]
},{...}]
```

Current pipeline:

```
            var mongoPricePreferences = await AggregatePipeline()
           .Match(x => x.UserId == userId)
           .Lookup(
                ProductItemCatalogueRepository.CollectionName,
                "SeriesIds.SeriesId",
                "petchem_price_specifications.id",
                "joins")
               .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(
                  BsonDocument.Parse(@"
                       {
                          $project: {
                              SeriesIds : {
                                  $map : {
                                      ""input"": { ""$zip"" : { ""inputs"" : [""$SeriesIds.SeriesId"", ""$joins.price_offerings""]}},
                                      ""as"" : ""el"",
                                      ""in"" : {
                                          ""SeriesId"" : {""$arrayElemAt"" : [ ""$$el"", 0]},
                                          ""SeriesEntitlements"" : {""$arrayElemAt"" : [ ""$$el"", 1]}
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }"))
             .As<PricePreferenceWithEntitlements>()
           .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

I think I'm stuck with the non type-safe version of Lookup due to the C# Mongo driver not being able to represent a field of a document in an array (`SeriesIds.SeriesId` and `petchem_price_specifications.id`) - it crashes when using a SelectMany. I would like to try clearing up the project stage though, rather than having that massive `AppendStage` block. I thought I may be able to handle the `Project` stage with something like

```
.Project<BsonDocument, PricePreferenceWithEntitlements>(
       x => new PricePrefenceWithEntitlements {
             UserId : userId,
             SeriesIds : <Some representation of the map/zip here>
       })
```

but couldn't see how to inject a bit of query into the projection.

Comment: official driver can't do advanced queries like this in a type-safe manner. [here's an alternative approach.](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/overcoming-the-limitations-of-mongodb-c-driver-1110)